# Is there a creeping plant that will absorb pollen, dust and pollutants?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations, flowers

I live in an apartment on the 10th floor & facing a major road. As a result fine dust and pollen make their way into my bedroom easily at night when I keep the window open.

I have allergic bronchitis and am allergic to these fine particles. I am suffering a lot due to this.

So as a solution I was thinking of planting a creeping plant which will absorb these particles. I live in Maharashtra, India.

I would like to have recommendations from you people for this, maybe if somebody has already faced this problem. So can you please recommend plants which grow in my climate?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any plants that absorb pollen but I did recently hear of a window screen that can filter pollen. Check out http://pollentec.com/

NASA did a Clean Air Study to try and identify plants that could be used to purify the air in enclosed spaces such as space craft. Here's a list of [air filtering plants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_air-filtering_plants).

For pollen, dust and other particles I think you'll want to look into a good HEPA air purifier.

Answer (score 5):

In general the air quality in Pune is not so good especially in the central areas. I would agree with [OrganicLawnDIY's suggestion](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/8306/2691) that you get a air purifier.

You can also try closing the windows while sleeping, as that will reduce the dust getting in. My experience living in Pune has been that the dust mostly accumulates during the day time, so make sure you close the windows during day time.